# How to remove figure label using caption2?

Tags: floats, captions

I'm aware I can use `\caption*{Some caption}` from the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption).

How can I do this with `caption2` package?

Comment: Welcome! Er... why would you want to use an obsolete package rather than the current one which has superseded it?

Comment: @cft Because I'm writing an article based on a template that uses this package.

Comment: If you mean you are submitting to a journal and must use this template, that's understandable. Otherwise, don't use the template!

Answer (score 6):

The `caption2` package offers `\captionlabelfalse` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption2}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\Large A
\captionlabelfalse         % don't show the caption label
\caption{A figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}  % correct figure counter
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\Large B
\caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Please note that the `figure` counter gets incremented anyway, so if that is not desired one have to correct it manually (by adding -1 to it after `\caption`).

If one prefers using the `\caption*` notation this could be accomplished by redefining `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption2}

% Redefine \caption to support \caption*
\makeatletter
\let\caption@ORIGINAL\caption
\def\caption{%
  \@ifstar
    {\captionlabelfalse          % don't show the caption label
     \addtocounter{\@captype}{-1}% correct figure/table counter
     \renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}% suppress LoF/LoT entry
     \caption@ORIGINAL[]}%
    {\caption@ORIGINAL}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\Large A
\caption*{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\Large B
\caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

BTW: The documentation of the `caption2` package could be found here: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/HEAD/tree/branches/1.x/doc/anleitung.pdf?format=raw (Unfortunately it's only available in German.)

Please note that the `caption2` package is now obsolete for more than 12 years. Is it possible to update the template? If any questions occur regarding rewriting the `caption2` stuff so the regular `caption` package will be used instead, please don't hesitate to write me an e-mail. My e-mail address can be found in the README of the `caption` package bundle which can be found here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption

Answer (score 2):

Heed the warning of `caption2`:

```
Package: caption2 2015/09/15 v2.2-100 Customising captions (AR)

Package caption2 Warning: ****************************************************
(caption2)                THIS PACKAGE IS OBSOLETE:
(caption2)                This package attempts to provide an `caption2'
(caption2)                package v2.0/2.1 author environment so that OLD
(caption2)                documents can be successfully processed. It should
(caption2)                NOT be used for NEW documents! New documents should
(caption2)                use the regular `caption' package v3.x instead.
(caption2)                ****************************************************
```

You can emulate `\caption*` by not using `\caption` at all. Merely insert an appropriate space between the image and the caption (`\abovecaptionskip`) and set the text as usual:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption2,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image}
    \caption{A figure}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image}

    \vspace{\abovecaptionskip}%
    A figure% \caption*
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that the caption from this template has some special "effects" like different font, style (bold), delimiter ('.' instead of ':'), etc..

Comment: @orangesky: Do you know what style they set? Also, what does it matter what delimiter they use, as this doesn't form part of `\caption*`...

Comment: Try using `{\captionfont A figure}` for the unnumbered caption.